# Why doesn't this click handler work in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code in my page:

```
var offer_link = $('<a>').addClass('fc-offer-link');
offer_link.click(function() {
    alert('Hello');
});

offer_link.attr('href', "#" + this.id);
offer_link.append(this.subject);

this.list_item = $('<li>');
this.list_item.append(offer_link);
```

But even though the link appears on the page, the handler never gets called.  What's going on?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to load using `$(document).ready()` before you install the click handler?  Or running the javascript ion the body of the document at the end of the document (not in the HEAD section)?

Comment: What does `this` refer to? Also, I'd hazard a guess that changing to `$(offer_link).live('click',function(){ alert(...); });` might work.

Comment: `this` is an object that gets created dynamically, and constructs snippets of HTML which the calling function then grabs and inserts into the DOM.

Comment: I believe you can't add event listeners to elements not in the DOM. Try moving the event registration after the `append()`s.

Comment: @Inerdia Looks fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/Xbvh5/

Comment: The `$(offer_link).live('click',function(){ alert(...); });` does not work.

Comment: I tried moving the event registration until after the `offer_link` was inserted into the DOM.  It didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisB Are you sure you've copied the code into your question correctly? Given that `this` and the properties `id` and `subject` are valid and you're eventually adding `list_item` to the document, it should work

Comment: I have copied the code exactly as it appears.  There are no errors generated in the console, the handler just never triggers.  I tried creating a simple test case, but I cannot reproduce the problem in the smaller case.

Comment: How are you appending the the list item? Could it be that you are doing anything which destroys the DOM element and creates it again? And what is `this` here?

Comment: Ah ha!  That was what was happening.  The HTML was getting inserted using `$('#my_list').html(my_new_list.html())`.  Changing that to `$('#my_list').replaceWith(my_new_list)` fixed the problem, obviously.

Comment: @ChrisB In future, see the first comment (SSCCE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be where the item got inserted into the DOM.  It was being inserted using:

```
$('#my_list').html(my_new_list.html())
```

It should have been using:

```
$('#my_list').replaceWith(my_new_list)
```

Comment: Yes, when you use the `html` method, you are basically serializing DOM elements into a string. If you set the HTML string, new elements will be created which are different from the ones you bound event handlers to.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to append the link to an element, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var link = $("<a>Click Me!</a>").addClass("fc-offer-link").appendTo($("#div1"));
        if (link){
            link.click(function(){
                alert("Hey there!");
            });  
        }   
    });
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

**EDIT**: Not sure why I was downvoted, but here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rm4ub/)

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder See the JSFiddle link in the question comments, there is nothing wrong with binding the event handler before the element is injected into the document

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: It doesn't matter whether the handler is bound before or after the link is added to the DOM.